# Three circles intersect at one point.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, analytic-geometry, circles

If three circles intersect at one point then there's unique $x$ and $y$ coordinate values such that the following equations are satisfied:

$$(x-x_i)^2 + (y-y_i)^2 = r_i^2$$

Where $i=1,2,3$

Taking difference of consecutive pairs would give me 3 linear equations with 2 unknowns which I can solve for the unknowns.

Is that the correct way to find the $x$ and $y$ values?

Comment: Has it worked for you? If it does, and you don't have to worry about time, it *is* one way to find $x$ and $y$.

Comment: I solved for x and y sure. Not parameterized I'm just trying to find the point of intersection.

Comment: There is no correct or wrong way to find an answer. If it works, you can use it.

Comment: It is a good way to do it. Using the same procedure, you would find the coordinates of the center of the circle going through 3 points and one of the equations will give the radius.

Comment: If a circle goes through origin then there are x,y,x^2, y^2 terms only,no constants,  with coefficients of x^2, y^2 same. This can be used to advantage.

Answer (score 0):

I'd not say that this is *the* correct way to find the point of intersection, but it certainly is *one* correct and reasonable way.